# Induction of twisted character isomorphic to twist of induced character

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G=GL_2(F)$ for $F$ a non-Archimedean local field of characteristic $0$. Given a smooth representation $(\pi,V)$ of $G$ and a character $\psi$ of $F^{\times}$, we define the twist of $\pi$ by $\psi$ to be the smooth representation $(\psi\pi,V)$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
\psi\pi(g)=\psi(\det(g))\pi(g).
\end{equation*}

A character $\chi$ (by character I mean a continuous homomorphism to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$) of the torus $T = \begin{pmatrix}* & 0 \\ 0 & * \end{pmatrix}$ is of the form $\chi = \chi_1 \otimes \chi_2$, where $\chi_1,\chi_2$ are characters of $F^{\times}$. Given a character $\psi$ of $F^{\times}$, define $\psi \cdot \chi = \psi\chi_1 \otimes \psi\chi_2;$ this is another character of $T$. As such, we can inflate it to $B$, the Borel subgroup $\begin{pmatrix}* & * \\ 0 & * \end{pmatrix},$ to get a smooth representation of $B$. A computation shows that, considered as a representation of $B$,
\begin{equation}
\psi\cdot\chi=(\psi \circ \det|_B)\otimes \chi.
\end{equation}
From here, my textbook claims it is immediate that
\begin{equation}
\text{Ind}_B^G \psi \cdot \chi \cong \psi \cdot \text{Ind}_B^G \chi
\end{equation}
where $\text{Ind}_B^G \chi$ denotes the smooth induction of $\chi$ to $G$. I am failing to see this.

As I understand, the above two objects consist of the following. Firstly, $\text{Ind}_B^G \psi \cdot \chi = (\Sigma, X_1),$ where $X_1$ is the space of $G$-smooth (by $G$-smooth we mean given $f$, there is a compact open subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $f(gk)=f(g)$ for all $g \in G, k \in K$) functions $f:G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that satisfy $f(bg)=\psi \cdot \chi(b)f(g)$ for all $b \in B, g \in G$. This space of functions is acted upon by right-translation which we denote by $\Sigma$.

Secondly, the object $\psi \cdot \text{Ind}_B^G \chi = (\psi\Sigma,X_2)$ consists of the function space $X_2$ of $G$-smooth functions $f:G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ whereas now they satisfy $f(bg)=\chi(b)f(g)$ for all $b \in B, g \in G$. These functions are acted upon by $\psi\Sigma$ in a way defined at the start of the post.

I need advice on constructing a $G$-equivariant invertible linear map $L:X_1 \rightarrow X_2$.

Answer (score 2):

The map
\begin{align*}
L: \phi \text{Ind}_B^G \chi &\rightarrow \text{Ind}_B^G \phi \cdot \chi \\
f &\mapsto \phi\cdot f
\end{align*}
does the job, where $\psi \cdot f$ is defined by $(\psi \cdot f)(g) = \psi(\det{g}) f(g)$.

Comment: This holds for any character of $B$ and any dimension $n$ also right?